# Настройка 10Gb сетевой карты под Linux при работе с ethernet фреймами

Tags: linux, сокет, lan, ethernet

Не уверен, что вопрос соответствует правилам, но всё же.

Есть 10Gb карточка (марка не важна, т.к. результат повторялся и на двух других, отличных от этой) и `Debian Buster`, соединенный оптикой напрямую с машинкой-источником данных. Организован поток данных ~9Gb, состоящий из ethernet фреймов размера ~9000 байт, в которых кроме MAC отравителя, МАС получателя, кастомного EtherType и счетчика пакетов ничего нет.

Замеры утилитами `wireshark`, `tshark`, `tcpdump` (хотя они всё равно все работают через одну библиотеку) показывают пропуск примерно каждого второго пакета. Самописный кривой код показывает примерно то же. При этом под `Windows 7` тот же `wireshark` (при большом выделенном буфере) ловит все пакеты.

Проверка пропускной способности сети утилитой `iperf3` на TCP трафике даёт стабильные 9.8Gb.

```
# uname -a

Linux debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2 (2019-08-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux


# ifconfig enp1s0

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 12000
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.255.255
        inet6 fe80::b2c5:54ff:feff:f37f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b0:c5:54:ff:f3:7f  txqueuelen 3000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1501482032  bytes 13216245041216 (12.0 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1501472982  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75  bytes 7809 (7.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 34  memory 0x90400000-90410000  



# ethtool -g enp1s0

Ring parameters for enp1s0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     1365
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     2048
Current hardware settings:
RX:     1365
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     2048

# ethtool -k enp1s0

Features for enp1s0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
    tx-checksum-ipv4: on
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: on
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
    tx-tcp-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off [fixed]
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on
rx-vlan-filter: on
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off [fixed]
rx-all: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
```

Я плохо знаю сетевой стек и откровенно "плаваю" при настройке сети, поэтому прошу помощи сообщества или хотя бы вектора, в котором необходимо копать. Особенно интересует эта строка `RX errors 0  dropped 1501472982  overruns 0  frame 0`

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть в эту сторону и потестить: https://ya-zero.github.io/linux/nic/nic_tune/

Comment: Вот пример из прода сервера с 10gb карточкой от intel от моего хорошего товарища:
options ixgbe MQ=1,1
options ixgbe RSS=8,8
options ixgbe InterruptThrottleRate=1,1
options ixgbe DCA=2,2
options ixgbe FCoE=0,0
options ixgbe LRO=0,0

Comment: @nobody Частично описанные действия пробовал, попробую остальное - отпишусь

Comment: Вот ещё скриптец от intel для распределения прерываний который используем https://github.com/majek/ixgbe/blob/master/scripts/set_irq_affinity

Comment: Непонятно, действительно ли ядро теряет пакеты или их теряет libpcap. С одной стороны, если бы ядро теряло половину пакетов, ни о какой скорости 9.8Gbps на TCP речи бы не шло. С другой стороны, отношение dropped к RX packets составляет те же самые 1:1. А не может ли ядро дропать пакеты потому что они кривые? Например, что будет, если после очистки счётчиков интерфейса потестировать тем же самым iperf'ом по UDP, создав трафик в районе 9.5Gbps?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev На UDP ранее проверял и смог выжать 8.05Gb, на счетчики, увы, не смотрел. Все эксперименты смогу провести только серез 2 дня(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большинстве случаев в linux требуется подтюнить драйвер, настройки ядра и, возможно, перераспределить прерывания по ядрам. Ниже представлены примеры рабочих параметров с 10g машин под debian.

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf 
options ixgbe MQ=1,1 
options ixgbe RSS=8,8 
options ixgbe InterruptThrottleRate=1,1 
options ixgbe DCA=2,2 
options ixgbe FCoE=0,0 
options ixgbe LRO=0,0


# cat /etc/sysctl.conf

# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296

# No swappiness
vm.swappiness = 0 
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.wmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608
net.core.wmem_max = 8388608

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 30000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 1800

net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 1 
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_announce = 1 

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 20
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1 
net.core.somaxconn = 16384
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 65536
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1 
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0 
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0 
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 51200   76800   102400
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 51200   76800   102400
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5 
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0 
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = htcp
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 1800
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 512000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 512
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 1024
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 2048

kernel.panic = 60
```

Прерывания можно перераспределить скриптом от intel: https://github.com/majek/ixgbe/blob/master/scripts/set_irq_affinity

Answer (score 3):

На данном этапе вопрос закрыт: я слишком доверял утилитам (`wireshark`, `tshark`, `tcpdump`) в сочетании со строкой `dropped 1501472982` от `ifconfig`. Что на самом деле такое эти `dropped` (присутствующие также в выводе упомянутых программ), нужно разбираться в каждом случае отдельно, но это не безвозвратно потерянные пакеты.
В моём случае достаточно было увеличения этих параметров ядра:

```
net.core.rmem_max
net.core.wmem_max
net.core.rmem_default
net.core.wmem_default
net.core.optmem_max
```

На имеющемся потоке данных самописный код (немного модифицированная версия вот этого https://github.com/hundeboll/rawsend) ловит каждый пакет, попытка замерить максимальную пропускную способность дала ~9.9Gb.